# How to make an async event run continuously?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am creating a little console app that is just in proof-of-concept stage right now.  The idea is that it will query 3rd party API's for events on their end.  (That part is all working just fine).

When an event arrives, we need to stick the json string for that event into a sqlite db on our side.  At the same time, I need a process running in the same app that is continuously looking for records in the sqlite table, and when it finds one, it handles it.

Here's what I have so far... (again, this is just a proof of concept while I learn the basics of how to set this up)...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = CheckEventsAsync();
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        DataAccess.InsertData("INSERT INTO events(value) VALUES ('this is an event');");
    }
}

static private async Task CheckEventsAsync()
{
    DataTable dt = await DataAccess.LoadDataAsync("SELECT * FROM events");
    foreach (var dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got an event!");
    }
}
```

The problem is that CheckEventsAsync() only ever fires once, and then when the 5 second timer goes off an a record is added to the table, nothing happens.

Am I going to need to use an EventHandler (with a delegate, etc) to make this work?  Or is it possible w/o doing it that way?

Thanks!

Oh, almost forgot... (this works in that it returns a data table if there is data, and null if not.  But I'm not sure I'm doing  it right for the overall goal)...

```
    public static async Task<DataTable> LoadDataAsync(string txtQuery)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_source);
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = txtQuery;
            var task = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(task);
            connection.Close();
        }
        if (dataTable != null & dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            return dataTable;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I see from the answers so far that I did a bad job of asking the question.  I need to have two processes running:

1. The first process will listen for 3rd party events and add them to the sqlite table.  This is simulated with the 5 second timer.  But in reality, there will not be a timer inside a `While(true)` loop.  It will be a WebSocket Listener.
2. The second process will watch for records in the database and handle them. So, CheckEventsAsync() needs to be a listener that triggers without the method being called.

The two need to operate within the same app, but independent of each other.

I hope I am making sense?

Comment: After your edit I'm not sure what the question actually is. You described what each of the processes should do, so just implement it.

Comment: Since both run in the same process - you don't need to look at database to get new rows - just pass row from process that gets it to process that handles it. Of course you may still insert in database in case application will crash, to not miss any rows.

Comment: Your `SetConnection(); using (_connection) { ... }` code has a very strong code smell. You shouldn't be using a field-level variable inside a `using(...)` statement. Can you post the rest of your `DataAccess` class?

Comment: @Evk, there will be multiple processes listening to multiple 3rd parties, all adding entries into the table.  I would like a single process that monitors the table and handles events.

Comment: But they will all run in the same process, or can be different processes (I mean OS processes)?

Comment: @Enigmativity, fair point. Still in development.  I will fix that, but it's OT for now.

Comment: @Evk, same OS process. What I really want is a Queue.

Comment: (I was just hoping to use the sqlite table instead of an actual message queue)

Comment: Is the queue so that you can have multiple produces and one consumer?

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes, exactly

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - So why not use `ConcurrentQueue`?

Comment: Why not use background workers. Here is something you could use https://www.hangfire.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all that is running in the same OS process - you don't need to constantly poll database for new events. Instead - use in-memory queue to which all producers push data and consumer, well, consumes. You can still insert data into sqlite table to handle the case when process crashes and some items are left unprocessed. Here is some code (for illustration purposes - in your real application you will not have `Thread.Sleep` and such of course):

```
class Program {
    static readonly BlockingCollection<ItemToProcess> _queue = new BlockingCollection<ItemToProcess>(new ConcurrentQueue<ItemToProcess>());
    static readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // get all unprocessed items from database here and insert into queue
        var producerThread = StartProducer(_cts.Token);
        var consumerThread = StartConsumer();
        Console.ReadKey();
        // cancel
        _cts.Cancel();
        // wait for producer thread to finish
        producerThread.Join();
        // notify there will be no more items
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        // wait for consumer to finish
        consumerThread.Join();
    }

    static Thread StartProducer(CancellationToken ct) {
        var thread = new Thread(() => {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested) {                    
                // also insert into database here
                _queue.Add(new ItemToProcess() {
                    Value = "value"
                });
                // imitate delay
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }) {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thread.Start();
        return thread;
    }

    static Thread StartConsumer() {
        var thread = new Thread(() => {
            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                try {
                    // process
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                    // delete from database here
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    // handle
                }
            }
        }) {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thread.Start();
        return thread;
    }
}

class ItemToProcess
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: excellent!  This will give me something to chew on tomorrow.  It's past midnight and I need to get to sleep.  But I will implement this first thing in the AM.

Comment: no idea why someone down-voted this after I up-voted it :-(

Comment: A `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(5000); ... }` is a bad idea as it prevents the app closing cleanly. You would need to kill threads to get out of the app, but no references to the threads have been kept. This may be a good start to solving the problem, but it's fairly inelegant at this point and is not the best answer to the problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity that was just a sketch illustrating idea, but you have a point. I modified example code.

Comment: Nothing in the final product will use anything like `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(5000); ... }`.  I just used it in the OP to illustrate events arriving a various times.

Comment: @Evk, you are awesome!  Can I ask you to explain CancellationTokenSource?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston it is used to notify our dummy producer to stop producing items. You can lookup its usage in docs, it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this:

```
static readonly BlockingCollection<ItemToProcess> _queue = new BlockingCollection<ItemToProcess>(new ConcurrentQueue<ItemToProcess>());

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDisposable inserts =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                _queue.Add(new ItemToProcess() { Value = "value" });
            });

    IDisposable checks =
        new CompositeDisposable(
            Disposable.Create(() => _queue.CompleteAdding()),
            _queue
                .GetConsumingEnumerable()
                .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
                .Subscribe(item =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                }));
}
```

This handles all of the threading and makes it easy to close the app. Just call `inserts.Dispose()` and `checks.Dispose()` just before exiting.

NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits.

Comment: And how it handles internally that enumerating `GetConsumingEnumerable` is blocking? I mean to "gracefully" exit you usually need to call `CompleteAdding` or use `GetConsumingEnumerable` overload which accepts cancellation token.

Comment: @Evk - Ta, muchly. Fixed it.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you!  I up-voted this, but marked Evk's as the answer because it fist better in the overall project, much of which I kept out of the OP to keep things brief.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is outside the five second loop, so of course it only fires once.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't have enough reputation to edit or comment the original post. Writing an answer was my only option. Only trying to help the guy out. No reason to downvote.

Comment: @Aaron - Sorry, I appreciate your frustration, but that's the rules of the site. You just need to go get 50 points to start commenting. It doesn't take long.

Comment: upvoted to negate the downvote, also to help the Aaron getting 50 points.